# YUV to RGB in iOS5 with OpenGLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, yuv

Hy everyone,

I try to convert yuv data (yuv420p) in rgb data in ios 5 with OpenGLES. I already had a look at the GLCameraRipple Demo from Apple, but that did not worked for me.

Have anybody tried this before and can help me?

Cheers

Comment: What didn't work about it? Apple provides all the code required to take in YUV data and convert those frames to RGB right in that example. You're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: The Demo is using a biplanar format, but yuv420p is a planar yuv format. That is the problem!!

Comment: @TheRock that should just mean adjusting your texture sampling; the conversion is the same.

Comment: @Tommy, Apple supports only yuv biplanar and ARGB interleaved. Hence, the conversion is not allowed

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu `gl_FragColor = yuvToRGB * texture2D(yuv420pSource, coordinate);`.

Answer (score 0):

The GLCameraRipple doesn't use RAW YUV data. It uses a frame buffer straight from the camera. Getting the GLCameraRipple to work with raw YUV data is not possible because you cannot layer back a manual created buffer.